# slidify (io2012): how to change the slide size according to screen resolution?

Tags: r, slidify

Hello all and sorry if this is a daft question. I've been playing around with slidify, and I think it rocks, even though I am a relative CSS newbie.

It sems to me that the "screen area" of slidify/io2012 is fixed -- on my laptop with 1366x768 it fits nicely, with only minimal black borders. But, only my desktop with a 1920x1080 there is huge black border. Should I present this via a beamer in fullHD, I also see the black border, and the actual slide is very small -- a lot of wasted space.

Is there a way to set the slide size relative to resolutions, or even a way to manually set the slide size somewhere? I apologise if this is trivial...

Many thanks for any help or pointers!

Answer (score 2):

I've dug a bit around and this might be helpful: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/185

In a nutshell: screen size changing is not implemented (yet?), but you can zoom in your browser to fit the screensize (`C-+` to increase, `C--` to decrease). Pressing `w` turns on 4:3 resolution if you need that. Pretty nifty!

Comment: Is there still no other solution available to rescale the slide size according to the screen resolution?